# Succint syntax of converting to Map and accessing element

Tags: scala, syntax

I'd like to access values of a list converted to a Map in the syntactially most correct and immediate way. I seem to be missing something, as

```
val lit = List(('a',1), ('b',2), ('c',3))
val m = lit.toMap
println( m('c') )
```

obviously works as expected, printing 3.

However,

```
println( lit.toMap ('b') )
```

fails with a 'Type Mismatch', regardless of my attempt to put brackets around the lit.toMap expression. I must be missing something very silly, but what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List.toMap` takes an implicit parameter, when you write

```scala
lit.toMap
```

It will be compiled to

```scala
lit.toMap(Predef.$conforms[(Char, Int) <:< (Char, Int)])
```

So if you place `()` right after `toMap`, no matter `lit.toMap()` or `(lit.toMap)()` Scala compiler expects you to pass in the *implicit* parameter *explicitly*, so you need to write:

```scala
lit.toMap(implicitly[(Char, Int) <:< (Char, Int)])('b')
```

Or

```scala
lit.toMap.apply('b')
```